Bridge in a walled garden
There is a rectangular walled garden with six entrances labelled A to F in order, with each entrance connected to a central pavilion by a straight path:
╔═A═══B═══C═╗
║  \  |  /  ║
║   \ | /   ║
║    \|/    ║
║     P     ║
║    /|\    ║
║   / | \   ║
║  /  |  \  ║
╚═F═══E═══D═╝

Since it was first built, however, it has been realised that not all visitors are interested in the pavilion – they just want to see the pretty flowers and shrubbery lining the walls.
To please these visitors the landscaper proposes adding three new paths linking alternate entrances A, C and E pairwise. Some caveats arise though:

No two paths may cross at the same level and paths cannot branch between their endpoints.
Everything must stay within the garden walls.
Clearly the job is impossible without building bridges and rerouting the existing paths, but due to budgetary constraints the landscaper can only afford to build one bridge. Any number of paths may use it though.

How can the landscaper build the bridge and reroute the existing paths so as to accommodate the three new paths?

If more than one path may use the bridge, then don't they either cross or branch?

if you build a path directly from A to C as-is, does that count as crossing or branching the existing AD, BE, and CF?

@KateGregory That would count as crossing BP.

So the puzzle is to figure out how to put 9 paths with a budget of one bridge, right? (And the paths being ABCDEF to P, and AC, CE, EA)

@BenjaminWang rot13(Gur oevqtr pna or jvqre guna na vaqvivqhny cngu.)

That "basic" rule of garden design is fairly artificial, since actual garden design seems pretty much the opposite. But I've seen worse cases of artificial rules in puzzles.
Also, I feel tempted to write a joke answer that there's only 1 bridge allowed, but no constraint on the amount of portals...

@EgorHans Yeah, the "basic" part was fluff, and this is a British old-school garden, not a fancy furry portal paradise!

Here's one way it can be done:

 

The three gray paths are the new ones that pairwise-connect A-C, C-E, and E-A.

@JaapScherphuis Oops! Thanks for pointing that out.

Easily fixed - the same general idea works.

Here is the solution I came up with:

 
 This puzzle was inspired by the "additional adjacency problem" in Ringel and Youngs's proof of the Heawood conjecture.
 


I had a feeling it was somewhat connected to the 7-colouring of the torus, but that didn't really help.

Couldn't the path from A to P be replaced with a much simpler one, like the ones from B to P and C to P?

@JosephSible I wanted to keep the symmetry of the underlying rotation system.

Sorry to graffitify your picture, Parcly, no disrespect intended. This answer follows on from a comment by @JaapScherphuis.
One would expect to be able to extend a graph with one bridge to a K_7. We can regard the walls as paths themselves (maybe can walk along the top?). We draw three paths outside the garden (in red) and can draw three more paths within the garden in the green.
Before we did this, there were lots of regions that were not triangulated (e.g. ABPE), but now V-E-F = 7 - 21 + 14 = 0 as correct for a torus. So all regions are triangulated. We must have three of the new paths outside the walls, because that exterior region has six edges.

